# ERROR: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined"

Tags: mongodb

I am getting the above error code when trying to deploy to Heroku. Locally, everything works and I can post to the database, but it fails when I try to access the heroku URL.

I have looked at some of the other questions about this error but none of them seem to be helping me fix this...

here is my config:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const db = process.env.MONGO_URI;

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(db, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
    });

    console.log("mongoDB connected");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

Server.js:

```
const connectDB = require("./config/db");

connectDB();
```

.env:

```
MONGO_URI = "mongodb+srv://*****:*****@blog-1sbvb.mongodb.net/blog?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

Comment: Have you added the `MONGO_URI` to the Heroku environment variables?

Comment: @KRRISH  You are right! That is what I was missing. I used the command "heroku config:set MONGO_URI=myuri"   with myuri being the .env variable.  Thanks!!